# OpenShift ONLINE: rhc setup errors out

Tags: installation, openshift, openshift-client-tools

When trying to get a new OpenShift ONLINE app(actually two of them) setup I get:

```
You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://MYAPP.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://MYAPP.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 404 1427 ms
DEBUG: Response did not include a message from server: invalid character at "<!D
OCTYPE "
```

git version 1.7.11,
ruby version 1.9.3

The weird thing, I'm trying to access it from Windows machine, however I was able to setup the same app successfully on a Mac a couple days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the default server when you run rhc setup (unless you are running your own OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Enterprise instance), you should NOT put your app-domain.rhcloud.com url there, as it will not work.